# Why do LUIS app lose endpoint key if I use it in several apps?

Tags: azure-language-understanding

I have several LUIS apps, 6 normal and 5 dispatch. I assign the same endpoint key from a cognitive service en Azure to all of them. But it seems that there are always two that end up losing the resource somehow. 
Couldn't find any documentation about a limit on how many LUIS apps can use the same endpoint at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can assign the same subscription key/endpoint key to multiple LUIS apps assuming **they are in the same region**. Also, the authoring key in LUIS.ai is not the same as the endpoint LUIS subscription key in portal.azure.com. The authoring key allows you to author any LUIS app and the endpoint key allows you to query any LUIS endpoint. The endpoint key allows a quota of endpoint hits based on the usage plan you specified when creating the key. [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-boundaries#key-limits) gives you a detail on the key limits for different subscriptions.

Comment: Yes, but this is not a quota limit issue. The resource is disappearing from the luis app.

Comment: Do the resources disappear from just two specific apps? Could you also double check if both the apps are in the same region?

Comment: They are all on the same region. Now I applied one resource to the dispatch apps(5) and another to the non dispatch apps(6) and it seems to be working correctly.

Comment: I don’t think it is always with the same 2